# CSS - Setting buttons to 150% their recommended size

Tags: html, css, dynamic-resizing

I have a HTML button on a webpage in which the text turns bold upon hover. However, when this happens the button gets bigger, which I don't want to have to happen. I have therefore used some simple JavaScript to make the buttons 150% their size upon document.ready. However, I am trying to minimise use of JS, so is this possible in CSS alone?

Code sample:

```
<button id="b1">Test</button>
<style>
<!-- When you hover over the button, it resizes - I want the width to become 150% what it would be on page load. -->
#b1{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: 0;
}

#b1:hover{
    color: #33F;
    font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance,

-- Matthew

Comment: Any reason why you can't just give the buttons a fixed width?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Kodie Grantham: Nothing specific, just don't want to have to deal with figuring out sizes if I add more buttons.
Lemuel Botha: I can't post my OWN code cause it's a massive mess at the moment, but I will edit with some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

```css
  .btn1{
 background:#0095ff;
 border:0;
 outline:0;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 6px 15px;
 transition: all .4s ease;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    .btn1:hover{ 
 font-weight:600;
        background:#07c;
    }


    .btn2{
 background:#0095ff;
 border:0;
 outline:0;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 6px 15px;
 transition: all .4s ease;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 min-width:150px;
    }
   .btn2:hover{ 
 font-weight:600;
 background:#07c;
    }
```

```html
    This might be the Problem :
    <button class="btn1">Hello</button>

    <br><br><br><br>
    Solution - need to add min-width or width in button
    <button class="btn2">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Like I said in my comment (on the actual post), while having a specified width would work fine, I would rather not have to define the size for each button.